# PHP code is not working when there no data?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, uploadify

I'm doing data entry program based on PHP every thing is working no issue (still under construction) but there is a problem that I can't find a solution. The issue is when the database doesn't have any data the image path wont get registered.

Now I'm using uplodify to upload an image file at the same moment I'm sending some data as well. The data contains a name, contact details and description this will directly be inserted to the DB and I also upload image which will get saved in to a folder and the name get saved in the database. But this processes are handled by two different PHP files one is AddPOIPro.PHP which handles the data adding and the uplodify.php to handle file upload and the updating of the file name.

The first issue I had was uplodify was not adding the file name in the same row as the submitted data so what I did was to get the last ID and decrement it by one and the updated the row that works when there is data but when theirs no data it fails. So what should I do to over come this. Below is my complete scripts thank you for your time.

**Form**

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('lId.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Upl/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#imgUpload').uploadify({
        'auto'     : false,
        'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
        'height'   : 20,
        'width'    : 200,
    }
        // Put your options here
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sendData").click(function(){
    var name  = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("Descrip").value;
    var con = document.getElementById("ConInfo").value;
    var dataString = 'Name='+name+'&Descrip='+desc+'&ConInfo='+con;

    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:dataString,
      url:'AddPoiPro.php',
      success:function(data){
       if(data="Data inserted") {
          //alert("Data  Success");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: #060\">Data Saved</dive>";
          $('#msg').delay(1500).fadeOut();

        } else {
          //alert("Not Inserted");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: red\">Data Not Saved</div>";
        }
     } 
   });
  });
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Upl/uploadify.css" />

<title>AddPOI</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="poiid">ID :</label>
    <input type="text" name="poiid" id="poiid" readonly="readonly" style="width:70px;" value="<?php echo $tId; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Name">POI Name :</label>

    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Descrip" style="alignment-adjust:middle">POI Description :</label>
    <textarea name="Descrip" id="Descrip" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ConInfo">Contact Infomation :</label>
    <textarea name="ConInfo" id="ConInfo" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Img">POI Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="imgUpload" id="imgUpload" />
  </p>
  <p><div id="msg"></div></p>
  <p>  
  <div align="center">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" id="sendData" value="Submit" onclick="$('#imgUpload').uploadify('upload','*');" style="width:100px;" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Rest Data" style="width:100px;" />
  </div>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Process PHP**

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('connect.php');

$getId = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM poiinfo");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($getId);

$poiName = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$poiDes = $_REQUEST['Descrip'];
$poiCon = $_REQUEST['ConInfo'];

if($row['ID']== 1){

    $updLn = "UPDATE `poiinfo` SET `Name`='$poiName',`Des.`='$poiDes',`Contact`='$poiCon' WHERE 1";
    $updDone = mysql_query($updLn);
    if ($updDone){
        echo "Data inserted";
    }else {
        echo "Not Done";
    }  

}else {
 $dbData = "INSERT INTO poiinfo(`Name`, `Des.`, `Contact`) VALUES ('$poiName','$poiDes','$poiCon')";

        $putData = mysql_query($dbData);
        if ($putData){
            echo "Data inserted";
        }else {
            echo "Not Done";
        }
 }       
?>
```

**uplodify php**

```
<?php
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/

include ('../../POIWeb/connect.php');
include ('../../POIWeb/lId.php');


// Define a destination
$path = 'POIWeb/img/';
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path ; // Relative to the root

/*$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

        echo $fName;
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}*/

//if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);    
    $tId = $tId--;


    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

        $fName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
        $imgPath = "UPDATE poiinfo SET Img = '$fName' WHERE ID = '$tId'";
        mysql_query($imgPath);  

     echo '1';       

    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: And did you get any php error ? Check the apache log or the ajax result from your browser debugger.

Comment: your current implementation "`get the last ID and decrement it by one and the updated the row`"will fail when multiple insertions are made. ie two requests are made simultaneously and two rows are inserted to `poiinfo` but in uplodify.php both files will be updated to the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution to my problem had some help form the guys in StackOverflow Below is my full code is any one is having  the same problem similar to me you can use this code. And if it works for you pls put a vote for me thank you.

**My Data Entry Form**

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('lId.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Upl/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#imgUpload').uploadify({
            'auto'     : false,
            'swf'      : 'Upl/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'Upl/uploadify.php',
            'height'   : 20,
            'width'    : 200,
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png'
    });
        // Put your options here
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#save_data").click(function(){
    var name  = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("Descrip").value;
    var con = document.getElementById("ConInfo").value;

    var dataString = 'Name='+name+'&Descrip='+desc+'&ConInfo='+con;

    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:dataString,
      url:'AddPoiPro.php',
      success:function(data){
       if(data="Data inserted") {
          //alert("Data  Success");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: #060\">Data Saved</dive>";
          $('#msg').delay(1500).fadeOut();
        } else {
          //alert("Not Inserted");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: red\">Data Not Saved</div>";
          $('#msg').delay(1500).fadeOut();
        }
     } 
   });
  });
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Upl/uploadify.css" />

<title>AddPOI</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="poiid">ID :</label>
    <input type="text" name="poiid" id="poiid" readonly="readonly" style="width:70px;" value="<?php echo $tId; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Name">POI Name :</label>

    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Descrip" style="alignment-adjust:middle">POI Description :</label>
    <textarea name="Descrip" id="Descrip" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ConInfo">Contact Infomation :</label>
    <textarea name="ConInfo" id="ConInfo" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Img">POI Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="imgUpload" id="imgUpload" />
  </p>
  <p><div id="msg"></div></p>
  <p>  
  <div align="center">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" id="save_data" value="Submit" onclick="$('#imgUpload').uploadify('upload','*');" style="width:100px;" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Rest Data" style="width:100px;" />
  </div>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**My DataProcess PHP**

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('connect.php');

$getId = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM dbname");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($getId);

$poiName = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$poiDes = $_REQUEST['Descrip'];
$poiCon = $_REQUEST['ConInfo'];

if($row['ID']== 1){

    $updLn = "UPDATE `poiinfo` SET `Name`='$poiName',`Des.`='$poiDes',`Contact`='$poiCon' WHERE 1";
    $updDone = mysql_query($updLn);

    if ($updDone){
        echo "Data inserted";
    }else {
        echo "Not Done";
    }  

}else {
    $dbData = "INSERT INTO poiinfo(`Name`, `Des.`, `Contact`) VALUES ('$poiName','$poiDes','$poiCon')";        
    $putData = mysql_query($dbData);

    if ($putData){
        echo "Data inserted";
    }else {
        echo "Not Done";
    }
 }       
?>
```

This was really tricky the uploadify PHP but got it to work the way I want.

**Uplodify PHP (My Version)**

```
<?php
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/

include ('../../POIWeb/connect.php');
include ('../../POIWeb/lId.php');


// Define a destination
$path = 'POIWeb/img/';
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path ; // Relative to the root

/*$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

        echo $fName;
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}*/

//if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);    
    $tId = $tId--;


    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

        $fName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
        $imgPath = "UPDATE poiinfo SET Img = '$fName' WHERE ID = '$tId'";
        mysql_query($imgPath);  

     echo '1';       

    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
?>
```

This script is working flawlessly now if some face the same situation which I faced use this and see if it works for you and you're allowed to make any changes as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get Last id you can do Query As Like Following

```
SELECT `ID`
FROM `poiinfo`
ORDER BY `ID` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

If you face any more problem then you can knock me..

Comment: I have something similar to the one you show me but my problem is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a better approach

```
 $("#sendData").click(function(){
    //upload the file programatically (Method Call'upload')[http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/upload/]
    // echo the name of the uploaded file (make sure to rename the file for uniquiness)
    // create a hidden element with the filename as the value inside the form
    // call the ajax submit and submit the form. You can use (onuploadsuccess)[http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/] to trigger the element creation and ajax submit functions
 });
```

You current implementation can cause issues consider,
 *Request 1 : ID 10

 Upload 1 : ID 10

 Request 2 : ID 11

 Request 3 : ID 12

 Upload 2 : ID 12

 Upload 3 : ID 12*

Comment: The problem you said is happening to me I want to over come that the one you suggest looks good. I have put the file upload to auto mode and the echo the name of the file the fire the query back to the data base to insert the name and data. Can you give me a example how to do that I'm in the b lank how to do it.

Comment: I didn't do any changes in the java script all pages are here in the above question and the uplodify is embedded in the maine form it self